# Is there any requirements to connect application with sms gateway to send or recive message online?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application that will send a message at a pre-defined time.  Do I require an SMS gateway?  Or is there another way to send a message online?

Comment: Sending SMS online or HTTP messages?

Comment: I want to devlop an application that send message online in pre defined time

Comment: That's a broad topic. Asking for software recommendations on StackOverflow is off-topic. This site is for solving coding problems. If you have problems implementing that system, then we will help